# Using multiple send_keys() in Selenium Python not working

Tags: python, selenium, automation, splinter

I am using Splinter and Python to automate a website. I am able to use the `send_keys()` method in Selenium but can't send multiple keys at a time, for example `browser.driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')`

No error  or exception is being occurred, but code doesn't work as expected.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from splinter import Browser
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

executable_path = {'executable_path':'C:/Users/UserName/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe'}
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, options=options)

browser.visit('https://google.com/')
time.sleep(4)

#This is working
browser.driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys('hello world')

#This also works
browser.driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

#Not working
browser.driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')

#Not working
browser.driver.find_element_by_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

I have tried chaining the `send_keys()` method, but that also doesn't seem to be working.

```
#Not working
 browser.driver.find_element_by_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t')
```

This chaining method is throwing an exception as:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python Automation/Test 1/swap.py", line 18, in <module>
    browser.driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL).send_keys('t')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you cannot use multiple `send_keys()` methods in a chain
2. Using keys combinations is not supported by `chromedriver` for now

You can try to use, for example, `Firefox` instead of `Chrome` or below workarounds:

```
driver.execute_script("window.open();")
```

to open new tab instead of

```
browser.driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 't')
```

and

```
driver.close()
```

to close tab instead of

```
browser.driver.find_element_by_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```